# Angular: (Forwarding to) Routing with multiple variables

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I'm not even sure whether this is possible because I've never seen or done this before. I couldn't find anything alike in the documentation. However, basically what I want to achieve is something like this:

```
route1: /blog/author/1 ==> Redirects to route 2
route2: /blog/author/1/Jane_Doe ==> Redirects to route 3
route3: /blog/author/1/Jane_Doe/...
```

Even better would be if I could replace the `/` with `-` for the non-id variabeles. As such:

```
route1: /blog/author/1 ==> Redirects to route 2
route2: /blog/author/1/Jane_Doe ==> Redirects to route 3
route3: /blog/author/1/Jane_Doe-...
```

I tried the following:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ":id",
    redirectTo: ":id/:fullname"
  },
  {
    canActivateChild: [MetaGuard],
    path: ":id/:fullname",
    component: DetailedAuthorItemComponent,
    resolve: {
      author: AuthorResolver,
      posts: AuthorPostsResolver,
    },
  },
];
```

However, the first path doesn't work. I get the following error:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot redirect to ':id/:fullname'. Cannot find ':fullname'.`

Anyone that could help me out and knows wheter this is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You  can achieve this using the children of the routes property in angular routing. Something like this:

This is called the nested children concept in angular routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'blog',
  component: Component1, // The route here would be /blog
  children: [
     {
        path: 'author',
        component: Component2, // Basically the path here would be /blog/author
        children: [
           {
              path: 'id',
              component: Component3, // Basically the path here would be /blog/author/id
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
]
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I'm trying to achieve. I'm aware of child routing and I already have it implemented with lazy-loading in my different routing modules, but I want to achieve having different paths forwarding to the same URL whilst also having multiple variables in the routing.